# Is it possible to compare multiple values with one field?

Tags: c#

My question may not make much sense, so let me reiterate.
Let's say I have code that looks like so:

```
int value = 4;
if (value == 4 || value == 8 || value == 12) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Would it be possible to compare 4, 8, and 12 to value without rewriting "value ==", such as:

```
if (value == (4 || 8 || 12)) {
    doSomething();
}
```